# google cloud storage create file name automatically

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

i accessing google cloud storage by blobstore api, I would like to generate file names automatically instead of create it in the server.
actually i want to do that, because it is hard to me to create a unique file name every time the user upload file.
thank you

Comment: What language are you using? You should be able to create a UUID4 pretty easily.

Comment: thank you for your fast response

Comment: -1 you replied two times and not provided the language or specific requirements. Make clear what you need.

Comment: actually i am using python, and i think that uuid4 is a good solution,but i don't know how to assure that there is no duplications,i think that i should check if the file is existing every time i use uuid4 ,and if it is ! so i just generate another id ,what do you think ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Python you can simply use [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) to generate your random filenames like this:

```
import uuid

...

# with dashes
filename = uuid.uuid4()

# or without dashhes
filename = uuid.uuid4().hex
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an organised file name simply by just by using either computer name and Internet clock time, with a Smart-Phone you can use GPS day time year and map coordinates like in the case of geotagging. Everything is unique and readily available on computer or mobile rather than leaving a server to name the file.